# Difference between interaction terms and test for interaction

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, interaction

I am having difficulties in understanding the difference between interaction terms and test for interaction. I am using logistic regression models so maybe the concept is different compared to linear regression?

As far as I understood from [this](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpreting-interactions-in-regression/#:%7E:text=Adding%20interaction%20terms%20to%20a%20regression%20model%20can,is%20located%20in%20partial%20or%20full%20sun%20%28Sun%29.) explanation, interaction terms let you know how the relationship between two variables changes when a third variables assumes different values.
For example: how relationship between death and age changes according to sex (e.g. if sex=male or sex=female how the OR changes).
But from the interaction terms I can also know if there is a significant difference between the changes due to sex, is this correct? [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331244/how-to-test-if-an-interaction-is-significant-interaction-terms-or-model-compari) is the source from what I understood this.

So what is then the point of performing tests for interactio)? For instance, I run a logistic regression in males to obtain the OR for death and age and then I run the logistic regression for females to obtain the OR, and then I compare the two ORs using test for interaction.

What is the correct method to assume that two subgroups (e.g. males and females) have a significantly difference relationship between age and death? What are the differences between interaction terms and test for interaction?

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, I run a logistic regression in males to obtain the OR for death and age and then I run the logistic regression for females to obtain the OR, and then I compare the two ORs using test for interaction.

That is not the "test for interaction" that the [page you link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/331244/28500) describes. The test there is based on two nested models, not two separate models for males and females. One model includes predictors individually (e.g., `~ age + sex`) and the other including the interaction between them (often coded `~ age*sex` in R, which expands to `~ age + sex + age:sex`, with `age:sex` the interaction term). The two nested models are then compared by a likelihood-ratio test.

The "signficance" of the coefficients reported for a single model with interactions is typically evaluated instead by a *t*-test or Wald test. There's nothing wrong in principle with that, as in the limit of large sample sizes the results converge to those of the likelihood-ratio test.

There nevertheless can be some confusion about lower-level coefficients in such models, even with lower-level interaction coefficients when the model includes higher-level interactions, as their values depend on the coding of *interacting* predictors. The `Anova()` function in the R [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) can test all coefficients associated with a predictor in a joint *t*-test or Wald test. That overcomes those difficulties in interpreting the individual coefficients.

So the difference between the *properly constructed* "interaction test" based on two models and the *properly constructed* test of interaction coefficients in a single model is the difference between the likelihood-ratio test used in the first approach and the *t*-test or Wald test used in the second approach. [This UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqhow-are-the-likelihood-ratio-wald-and-lagrange-multiplier-score-tests-different-andor-similar/) explains how the tests typically reported for models fitted by maximum-likelihood methods differ.